# Subversion: Ignore a Directory in the Repo on Commit

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, ignore

I have all the boost header files in this repository and when I do a check in it takes a really long time to scan all those files that will never change.
Because I want users that checkout the project to be able to compile without installing boost I am in a pickle.

I want to checkout everything, and then ignore updates (there will never be any) on a directory.

Tortoise svn has a ignore-on-commit change list, but I cannot find anyway to add an entire directory to this list, and I do not fancy the idea of 'modifying' all the boost files so I can add them to this change list.

Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could use Subversion ["externals"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s04.html) to store the Boost header files in another Subversion repository. That way, Subversion won't need to scan that directory when checking for updates to your project, but users who check out your project will automatically get the whole thing including the Boost dependency.

Comment: From the link - "So, for example, if you want to commit changes that you've made in one or more of those external working copies, you must run svn commit explicitly on those working copies—committing on the primary working copy will not recurse into any external ones."
Sounds PERFECT, thank you very much

Comment: Seems like tortoise svn spent a lot of time and effort making their commit code operate through external links.  And it seems they forgot to make an off switch..  Oh well

Answer (score 2):

Additional to Greg's answer, you may also have a look on the possibility to update to a specific revision. Thus, you could make sure, a client would not get unintentionally any updates on the "Boost" project.

br, Marcel

Answer (score 0):

I came to this thread looking for a way to make an "atomic" commit of just some files and instead of ignoring some files on commit I went the other way and only commited the files I wanted:

```
svn ci filename1 filename2
```

Maybe, it will help someone.